# Connect to a https site with a given p12 certificate - CENTOS and curl

Tags: security, curl, ssl-certificate

I have given .p12 and .pem certificate from https owner, which im trying to connect with curl command on CentOS machine.

System returns following types of errors on my curl commands: 
***(I HAD TO ERASE HTTPS IN FRONT OF ALL CURL COMMANDS BECAUSE OF MY REPUTATION, BUT I CALL EVERY CURL COMMAND WITH HTTPS IN FRONT OF ://)***

**curl --cert root/XYZ.pem -G ://smsconnector.cz.o2.com/smsconnector/getpost/GP?action...**
    curl: (58) Unable to load client key -8178.

**curl --cert root/XYZ.pem --key root/XYZkey.pem -G ://smsconnector.cz.o2.com/smsconnector/getpost/GP?action...**
    same error: curl: (58) Unable to load client key -8178.

**curl --cacert XYZ.pem -G ://smsconnector.cz.o2.com/smsconnector/getpost/GP?action...**
     (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

I also tried to upload the .pem file to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ and then update, but i still get teh same errors.

**When i run openssl verify /root/XYZ.pem im getting this:**

/root/o2.pem: C = CZ, ST = ., L = "Marie Horakove 534/59, Praha, 170 00", O = "MERKUR CASINO a.s., ICO: 27151506", OU = ., CN = MERKUR CASINO a.s., emailAddress = JHasek@merkur-casino.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate

**When i run certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L im getting this:**

Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI

ET SMS Connector                                             u,u,u
ET SMS Connector - ET SMS Connector                          ,,

Can anyone pls tell me what im missing or what im doing wrong? My brain is about to explode :/.

Thx for any advice